# ERROR[6576][C-000018df] cdr_mysql.c: Failed to insert into database: (1062) Duplicate entry '' for key 'accountcode'

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

I am facing an issue while generating CDR report from freepbx / asterisk , we are getting blank report.

After troubleshooting , we fund error below error in CDR logs :

ERROR[6576][C-000018df] cdr_mysql.c: Failed to insert into database: (1062) Duplicate entry '' for key 'accountcode'

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Show some code to see what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You have created unique key for cdr.account code.

Since accountcode is same for all records of same users, you get that error.

Solution is remove key and create non-unique one

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same error in my logs. It appears that the mysql index was corrupted for the CDR table.

The fix was to run

```
mysql
use asteriskcdrdb
repair table cdr;
```

After that record insertion started running fine again.